Replacing comma in "If X, Y" with semicolon or period
Say there is a sentence like

If ice melts, then it becomes water.

Can you use a period or semicolon as well?



If ice melts; then it becomes water.




If ice melts. Then it becomes water.




Even the comma is usually unnecessary. Anything else is completely wrong in all normal contexts.

It would be incorrect to use a period or a semicolon. The clause "if ice melts" is subordinate (marked by the word "if") It is not an independent clause, so should not receive sentence punctuation.  It should not be ended by a period or semicolon.
In fact, as noted, a comma would not normally be needed here either.
